# (Autor, year) reference as well as citation style

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

The journal publisher has certain demands for citation and references which I have to fulfill. Following are the demands:

> All citations in text should refer to:
>   1. Upto two authors: Both authors last name without initials {comma} year of publication.
>   2. More than two authors: First author's last name followed by et al. {comma} year of publication.
>
> All references:
>   References should be sorted alphabetically and then chronologically. More than one reference from the same author(s) in the same year must be identified by the letters 'a', 'b', 'c' etc. placed after the year of publication.
>
> Examples:
>
> Reference to a journal publication: 
>   Van der Geer, J., Hanraads, J.A.J., Lupton, R.A., 2010. The art of writing a scientific article. J. Sci. Commun. 163, 51–59.
>
> Reference to a book: 
>   Strunk Jr., W., White, E.B., 2000. The Elements of Style, fourth ed. Longman, New York.

My efforts:

I tried to use `biblatex` for the first time since I read that it has more options for customization. I keep getting errors of the form

> command ---- already defined

for commands `\bibhand, \c@author, \citename, \bibfont, \Citeauthor`

I investigated the `.cls` file and found that it uses `natbib` package by including the line: `\RequirePackage[\@biboptions]{natbib}`. I tried with `natbib` package by including the following line:

`\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}`

It gave me an error, `Option clash for package natbib`. I have no clue what else to do. Could somebody guide me as to how I should generate the required reference and citation styles?

Note: I would preferably not change the `.cls` file since it is provided by publishers, but I can try out such solutions. The source for above text is: http://www.elsevier.com/journals/medical-image-analysis/1361-8415/guide-for-authors#68000

---

Update: I commented out the line in .cls file which loads natbib. Now problem with natbib is solved. I am trying to get desired results with natbib

Comment: The instructions say “without initials”, but the example has them.

Comment: Those are references, I meant in citations, there should be no initials, only the author's last name. Initials should come if there is ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it looks like you're using the document class `elsarticle` (which, as you've discovered, already loads the `natbib` package), you may want to execute the following command:

```
\biboptions{square,sort,comma,numbers}
```

This method is described in more detail on pages 2 and 3 of the user guide of the `elsarticle` package.

The `elsarticle` package comes with three separate bibliography style files: `elsarticle-num.bst`, `elsarticle-num-names.bst`, and `elsarticle-harv.bst`. The first or second of these should give you the formatting you require. (`elsarticle-harv`, in contrast, is meant for authoryear-style citation callouts, which doesn't seem to be what you want.)

Note that if `authoryear` was meant to be one of the options passed to `natbib`, one would have to specify it as an option to the document class:

```
\documentclass[authoryear{,<other options>}]{elsarticle}
```

Comment: I solved the problem with your help. I had to include options after `\documentclass[review,authoryear]{elsarticle}` as well as `natbib` options using `\biboptions{semicolon,round,sort,authoryear}`.\

Answer (score 1):

The option clash comes from the fact that your class file loads natbib `without` options, and you load it `with` some options. You should not load it, and give the options to the document class; the  class will  hand the options on to natbib.

Btw, `biblatex` has a natbib emulation mode. Probably loading biblatex with option `natbib=true` would suppress the error messages (not sure, though).

Comment: Yes. I already commented out the line in .cls file which loads `natbib`. Now problem with `natbib` is solved. I am trying to get desired results with `natbib`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only help for biblatex.

Comment: There are various problems with natbib (less than bibtex though). 1. I want the order of names in references as `last name, initials`. I can't get that. I want year of publication after list of names, then article name, journal name, issue number, page number. 

Can this be done in biblatex? If yes, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I've already done something more or less like that. I'll try to find it. The main advantage of biblatex is that it is relatively easy to customise and that it uses a latex-type syntax.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - I don't think the `elsarticle` document class supports biblatex/biber instead of natbib/bibtex.

Comment: @Mico Ok. That means I have to achieve the desired only with `natbib`